# Problema com campo DateTime no POST ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Campo DateTime ficando 01/01/0001 00:00:00, e não com a data anterior ao POST.

> Campo DataTime com os DataAnnotations (MODEL)

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Data de cadastro é obrigatório.")]
    [Display(Name = "Data cadastro")]        
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
```

> No GET do Create coloco a data atual no campo.

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PessoaModel pessoaModel = new PessoaModel();
        pessoaModel.Ativo = true;
        pessoaModel.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
        pessoaModel.UsuarioCadastro = "NICOLA BOGAR";

        return View(pessoaModel);
    }
```

> Campo DataTime fica corretamente ao abrir a View Create.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Quando realizo o post e tem algum erro de outro campo, esse campo DateTime vem dessa forma, 01/01/0001 00:00:00

```
    // POST: Pessoa/Create
    // Para se proteger de mais ataques, ative as propriedades específicas a que você quer se conectar. Para 
    // obter mais detalhes, consulte https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Handle,Ativo,TipoPessoa,CategoriaPessoa,Nome,CPF,RG,DataNascimento,CNPJ,IE,RazaoSocial,Sexo,EstadoCivil,Nacionalidade,EnderecoHandle,Contato,Auditoria")] PessoaModel pessoaModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Pessoa pessoa = mapper.ToModelForEntity(pessoaModel);

            db.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(pessoaModel);
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No seu bind eu vejo DataNascimento, mas não o DataCadastro.

Comment: Exatamente Leandro, acabei de ver isso,  mudei meu bind apenas para Exclude("Handle") que é minha PK, pois eu tinha criado o controller com minha entidade do entityframework , depois exclui as views e criei elas com meus models, e esqueci de mudar os binds.

Answer (score 1):

Isso deve ocorrer devido ao fato de que sua propriedade não é **nullable**

altere a sua propriedade para o código abaixo:

```
public DateTime? DataCadastro { get; set; }
```

Dessa forma, a sua propriedade poderá receber valores nulos, ou seja, quando esta data não é preenchida a propriedade ficará nula.

Assim, após o retorno de um post, o campo continuará em branco.

Quando a propriedade não é **nullable**, o DateTime, por não ser nulo, irá assumir o valor default **"01/01/0001 00:00:00"** no seu codebehind, quando o mesmo não for preenchido, provocando esse efeito descrito por você.